# Code copied from a book won't compile. Deprecated or typo?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

This is a program from a free c++ ebook, but it won't compile.
At first I typed it out, but upon realizing that it wouldn't compile I tried copying out of the ebook directly into codeblocks 13.12.
It still won't compile. The ebook is from 2010 so maybe the code doesn't follow current standards or there is a syntax typo somewhere.
Please help me figure out what is wrong.

The error is:

```
error: extra qualification 'Critter::' on member 'operator=' [-fpermissive]|
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Critter
{
public:
    Critter(const string& name = "", int age = 0);
    ~Critter(); //destructor prototype
    Critter(const Critter& c); //copy constructor prototype
    Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c); 
op
    void Greet() const;

private:
    string* m_pName;
    int m_Age;
};

Critter::Critter(const string& name, int age)
{
    cout << "Constructor called\n";
    m_pName = new string(name);
    m_Age = age;
}

Critter::~Critter() //destructor definition
{
    cout << "Destructor called\n";
    delete m_pName;
}

Critter::Critter(const Critter& c) //copy constructor definition
{
    cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
    m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
    m_Age = c.m_Age;
}

Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c) 
{
    cout << "Overloaded Assignment Operator called\n";
    if (this != &c)
    {
        delete m_pName;
        m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
        m_Age = c.m_Age;
    }
    return *this;
}

void Critter::Greet() const
{
    cout << "I’m " << *m_pName << " and I’m " << m_Age << " years old.\n";
    cout << "&m_pName: " << cout << &m_pName << endl;
}

void testDestructor();
void testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy);
void testAssignmentOp();

int main()
{
    testDestructor();
    cout << endl;

    Critter crit("Poochie", 5);
    crit.Greet();
    testCopyConstructor(crit);
    crit.Greet();
    cout << endl;

    testAssignmentOp();
    return 0;

}
void testDestructor()
{
    Critter toDestroy("Rover", 3);
    toDestroy.Greet();
}
void testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy)
{
    aCopy.Greet();
}
void testAssignmentOp()
{
    Critter crit1("crit1", 7);
    Critter crit2("crit2", 9);
    crit1 = crit2;
    crit1.Greet();
    crit2.Greet();
    cout << endl;

    Critter crit3("crit", 11);
    crit3 = crit3;
    crit3.Greet();
}
```

Comment: Remove the class qualifier from the function declaration here `Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c);` => `Critter& operator=(const Critter& c);`.

Comment: I'm guessing your book is expecting a non-standard compiler feature in the MS compilers.

Comment: Still doesn't compile. now the error is error: 'op' does not name a type. And the next error is: error: no 'void Critter::Greet() const' member function declared in class 'Critter' And the next 7 errors after that is this repeating error: error: 'class Critter' has no member named 'Greet'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the message says, there is an extra `Critter::` in

```
Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c);
```

As this is inside the class declaration, it must be a member of the class and doesn't need to be prefixed with the class name.

```
Critter& operator=(const Critter& c);
```

is the correct form.

The class name prefix is used only when the members are defined *outside* the class, like in the code later in the example.

Comment: now the error is error: 'op' does not name a type

Comment: And the next error is:   error: no 'void Critter::Greet() const' member function declared in class 'Critter'|

Comment: And the next 7 errors after that is this repeating error: error: 'class Critter' has no member named 'Greet'|

Comment: @Cody you seem to have "op" in your code on a line by itself for no reason. Possibly an error when the ebook was made. Remove the line that says `op`.

Comment: Oh wait it compiles when I comment out that random "op" in the class definition, but I don't know if that causes issues. That op IS there in the book, but I don't know what it does if anything.

Comment: Oh lol you beat me to it. This chapter introduces A LOT of new things that I haven't worked with before so I had no idea if that random "op" was just some weird syntax that I hadn't seen before. Thanks for the help. Good to know it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `Critter::` from that operator prototype

Comment: Still doesn't compile. now the error is error: 'op' does not name a type. And the next error is: error: no 'void Critter::Greet() const' member function declared in class 'Critter' And the next 7 errors after that is this repeating error: error: 'class Critter' has no member named 'Greet'

Comment: as pointed in the other answer - that `op` stuff must have been there by mistake, and needs to be removed.